# What happens if all puma's threads are handling a request and a new connection attempt happens?

Tags: multithreading, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I'm used to working with node, where the process will accept any number of incoming connections.

How is it different in Ruby/puma?

With puma I need to define a number of threads: does this number define the maximum number of requests the server can be processing simultaneously?

What happens if:

1. my server has long running requests
2. all threads are currently serving a request

and a new request comes in?

Does the socket get opened immediately but sit waiting until there is a free thread?
Does the socket connection stall until there's a free thread?
Or can the threads work on more than one request?

Answer (score 2):

> does this number define the maximum number of requests the server can be processing simultaneously?

It depends the number of Workers and Threads.

the max number of requests = Workers * Threads

> What happens if a new request comes in when there is no free thread

It will be blocked until there is at least one available worker thread.

> Does the socket get opened immediately but sit waiting until there is a free thread?

Yes.

> Does the socket connection stall until there's a free thread?

No.

Upon startup, Puma listens on a TCP or UNIX socket. And Puma is using round-robin to schedule requests across a fleet of workers and threads.
So the socket is always opened after Puma started.

> Or can the threads work on more than one request?

No.

One thread can handle exactly one request at a time.

For more detail, you can check https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/architecture.md